# How can I specify which image to show in search engine result pages from my Rich Snippet?

Tags: image, schema.org, rich-snippets

When I test my web page (which has [Schema.org](http://Schema.org) based content embedded within it) using the [Google Rich Snippets Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets), it displays the last image I have defined. I want it to show the first (primary) image.

Is there a way I can specify which image to use, or should I only be specifying one image?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give you an exact answer without either an example page of what you're testing or the schema.org content markup (i.e. - is this a Product?). However, my guess is you've defined multiple image itemprops. Instead, place the image itemprop around your primary image only and don't define any others.